# UI specification - refer to use case

Tags: use-case, uispec

I've written use cases and now I'm writing a UI specification. It's got only one screen but there are a bunch of little subtleties depending on the use case. Can I show my UI prototypes and then refer to a particular use case in the caption?

E.g. Figure 3. UI at the end of Use Case "Add New User - Alternative Flow B"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with one screen, you may want to show each variation (postcondition) of the screen, depending on the action. If all have the same precondition on that screen and the output or hidden action is different, then a list will suffice.